# How to add new Mime Type and associate with new application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mime-types, mime

I have a new file type ".xy2" and I would like to associate it with a custom application "shim". Does anyone know how to do it in a Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

In case someone comes across the same problem. I found the answer:

1. [Create](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1olY5Qzmbk8) new Mime Type. You can specify a different **mime-type**, in this video the author is using **text**, but you can use **application** or **image** etc.. All available types are listed in "usr/share/mime" folder.
2. Create your custom application and put a symlink into "usr/bin" folder.
3. Navigate to "~.local/share/applicatons" folder and create **new_mime_name.desktop** file.
4. Fill in information pertaining to your application. Here is an example of mine:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Terminal=false
   Icon=libreoffice-math
   Type=Application
   Categories=Application;Utility;
   Exec=shim %f
   MimeType=application/xy2;
   Name=shim
   Comment=shim tool
   ```
5. Associate file types with your application. Read [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2037497) from **OM55** user.
6. You might need to reboot your system.